# Javascript calculation library (Excel like web page without the grid)

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet

Is there any Javascript (or other NON-java ) CLIENT SIDE calculation library that will allow a complex excel spreadsheet to be posted online as a web page, and then can calculate directly on the web page when the user changes the values. Like a slimmed down web based excel.

I've seen JavaScript grid controls that offer simple calculation capabilities, but they do not allow you to import an existing sheet, or saving the sheet into an editable format for that matter.

I'm looking for a library (Client Side) that can read some sort of excel like file format (excel, wks, xml) , and interpret the cell references and formulas and then calculate on the web page, when the user changes a value.

The idea is to create a web page with the required form fields map those to the input cells on the sheet, and then map the results to the calculated values on the sheet.

Comment: Add different versions of Excel into this and *ka-boom*.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to do solely on the client.  You need to parse the XLS on the server then render the HTML and JS/JSON to the client.  That's how e.g. Google Spreadsheets does it.

Comment: It's possible, with HTML5 File API and other recent improvements, to parse XLS files in the browser.  I have started working on such a parser: http://niggler.github.io/js-xls/

Comment: It's definitely possible with xlsx files. You can unzip them with JavaScript then parse the individual xml files.

Comment: look at how angular parses template scope and controllers, dependency injection etc. definitely doable  ...

Comment: It's possible without any problems. Only time to code it

Answer (score 0):

Im actually working on a project that has some relevance here. Its an ongoing work on assignment from my employer.

They are using mediawiki, and want to have the ability to upload excel files to be displayed and client-side edited. My solution is to use PHPExcel for the initial grunt work of reading the excel file, then converting the data im interested in and passing it as json to my own js library that handles formula parsing and evaluation.

https://github.com/netbrain/spreadsheet-js

Feel free to contribute any missing excel functions :-)